# How to call methods in Dart portion of the app, from the native platform using MethodChannel?

Tags: native, flutter, platform

I am writing a native plugin that, in some cases, has to call functions in the Flutter portion of the app, written in Dart.
How it's achieved, is explained here:
https://flutter.io/platform-channels/

Furthermore, an example of invoking a method from the native/platform part towards the Dart/non-native is here:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/quick_actions

Now, this example is really nice in case the platform only needs to invoke a `method`, i.e. that call returns nothing/`void`, but in case it needs to invoke a `function`, i.e. needs a return value from the non-native/Dart part, I could not have found an example or documentation on the internet. I believe it can be implemented though, because in the native Java part, there is a method:

```
public void invokeMethod(String method, Object arguments, MethodChannel.Result callback)
```

So, there is a `callback` object that could have a return value from the non-native part - or, I am mistaken here, and there is currently no way of returning a value from the non-native Dart portion of the app?

Comment: Can you look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581385/flutter-plugin-call-back-on-dart ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The signature is `void setMethodCallHandler(Future<dynamic> handler(MethodCall call))`, so we need to provide a function at the Dart end that returns `Future<dynamic>`, for example `_channel.setMethodCallHandler(myUtilsHandler);`

Then implement the handler. This one handles two methods `foo` and `bar` returning respectively `String` and `double`.

```
  Future<dynamic> myUtilsHandler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
    switch (methodCall.method) {
      case 'foo':
        return 'some string';
      case 'bar':
        return 123.0;
      default:
        throw MissingPluginException('notImplemented');
    }
  }
```

At the Java end the return value is passed to the `success` method of the `Result` callback.

```
channel.invokeMethod("foo", arguments, new Result() {
  @Override
  public void success(Object o) {
    // this will be called with o = "some string"
  }

  @Override
  public void error(String s, String s1, Object o) {}

  @Override
  public void notImplemented() {}
});
```

In Swift, the return value is an `Any?` passed to the `result` closure. (Not implemented is signaled by the any parameter being the const `NSObject` value `FlutterMethodNotImplemented`.)

```
channel.invokeMethod("foo", arguments: args, result: {(r:Any?) -> () in
  // this will be called with r = "some string" (or FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for it! Do you have any sample code to call from IOS, Swift? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tom - added Swift example

Comment: @RichardHeap would this when the add isn;t active? For example when the android alarmmanager triggers a broadcast receiver?

Comment: How to use this in a Flutter plugin? the Android code will return the message to plugin.dart file method but how does the main.dart file use this method?

Comment: Your plugin needs an `initialize` or similar method. You call this from `main` or similar, passing some functions or a concrete implementation of an interface. The plugin remembers these/this. Then when you get a call from native it flows like this: main (the function/interface mentioned above) <- plugin/Dart <- method channel <- plugin/native <- native call

Comment: See also this answer where the question was "is it possible to not have the 'initialize' function" to which the answer is, of course, no. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58573536/is-there-in-flutter-a-way-of-calling-an-init-function-in-the-plugin-automatica/58576266#58576266

Comment: I have this error: `C:\...\ApplinkActivity.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
        CHANNEL.invokeMethod("foo", 12, new Result() {
  symbol:   class Result
  location: class ApplinkActivity`    
What is `Result`?

Comment: `Result` is an interface that you have to implement. Best to ask your own question, showing your code.

Comment: how do you instantiate `channel` on the java/kotlin side??

Comment: @codeKiller You construct it with `new MethodChannel` in your `onAttachedToEngine` implementation. For a good example, see: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/connectivity/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/connectivity

Comment: @RichardHeap When I am passing a String list as argument (i.e. channel.invokeMethod("foo", stringList, new Result())  it is giving me this error type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'. Any idea how it can be fixed??

Comment: @Ayush I'd need more context. Maybe ask a new question.

Comment: @RichardHeap what is the specific code on the dart-side (your default case with a // todo) that will trigger a FlutterMethodNotImplemented / notImplemented on the caller's end? I couldn't find a reference.

Comment: @entonio I think  `throw MissingPluginException('notImplemented');` should do it

Comment: @RichardHeap indeed, thank you. I took the liberty to edit your answer with it because I think the documentation is lacking.

Comment: @RichardHeap Can you guide on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581385/flutter-plugin-call-back-on-dart

Comment: Did not understand how to pass arguments from *native side*. Please give a sample. I really need to pass a list of objects

Comment: @DavidPapirov To pass a list use the platform equivalent - e.g. for Java use `ArrayList`. Pass it as the `args` parameter - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035150/how-to-pass-array-of-strings-with-invokemethod-from-native-to-flutter Note that you cannot pass an arbitrary object unless it's on the list of types supported by the message codec (e.g. string, map, etc). You could turn arbitrary objects into maps of supported items, or JSON, or write a custom codec.

Comment: @DavidPapirov See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61507418/how-to-put-arguments-from-swift-native-code-to-flutter/61509073#61509073