# How to pass Array of Strings with invokeMethod from Native to flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Based On this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor)
I want to pass array of strings as argument lik this :

```
Object obj = new String[] {"Hello","Bye"};
channel.invokeMethod("foo",obj, new MethodChannel.Result(){
...
);
```

but it shows error :

> Unsupported value: [Ljava.lang.String .

How can I do that?

Comment: hi, can you show me your onMethodCall ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `StandardMessageCodec` doesn't support arrays (except of `int` and `byte`). For objects, it supports Java collections, like `List` and `Map`. Change your array of String to a `List<String>`.

```
ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
args.add("Hello");
args.add("Bye");
channel.invokeMethod("foo", args, new MethodChannel.Result(){
```