# How to call a Dart method from an Android java Activity in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to call a dart method written in some .dart file in Flutter from a native android java activity, how can I do that?

Comment: You can't call it directly, but you could use ```EventChannel``` to send events to the dart code and in return the dart can execute the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to call methods in Dart portion of the app, from the native platform using MethodChannel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor)

Comment: Above links have same solutions that don't work for my case: calling a dart method in flutter end from android end. I tested them.

Comment: @Mohsen Emami Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Flutter**

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ScreenPage(),
    );
  }
}
class ScreenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenPageState createState() => _ScreenPageState();
}

class _ScreenPageState extends State<ScreenPage> {
  
  static const platform = const MethodChannel("myChannel");

  @override
  void initState() {
    platform.setMethodCallHandler(nativeMethodCallHandler);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<dynamic> nativeMethodCallHandler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
    print('Native call!');
    switch (methodCall.method) {
      case "methodNameItz" :
        return "This data from flutter.....";
        break;
      default:
        return "Nothing";
        break;
    }
  }



  
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //return ();
  }
 
}
```

**In Java**

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
//import io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView;


public class MyJavaFile extends FlutterActivity {

    Button clickMeButton;
    MethodChannel channel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        channel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "myChannel");

        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
        clickMeButton = findViewById(R.id.clickMeButton);
        
        clickMeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            
                channel.invokeMethod("methodNameItz", null, new MethodChannel.Result() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Object o) {
                        Log.d("Results", o.toString());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void error(String s, String s1, Object o) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void notImplemented() {
                    }

                });

            }
        });



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add channel(same as your payactivity channel) and create sethandler method in dart code.
   static const platform = const MethodChannel('flutter.native/helper');
   platform.setMethodCallHandler(nativeMethodCallHandler);
2. Create a handling method in dartcode :
   Future nativeMethodCallHandler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
   switch (methodCall.method) {
   case "UpdatePayment" :
   ........
3. invoke this method in your activity/java code :
   methodChannel.invokeMethod("UpdatePayment",null)

Comment: if you have arguments then pass it in place of null 
  ex : `Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();`
       `arguments.put("paymentResponse", s);
       `methodChannel.invokeMethod("UpdatePayment",arguments);`     
 in dart code you can retrive like this : paymentResponse = methodCall.arguments["paymentResponse"];