# How to invoke dart code from kotlin code?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, alarmmanager, flutter-method-channel

I have a flutter application where I have written kotlin code and I have set up [method channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-kotlin-tab) to communicate. There is a method in kotlin code which is invoked periodically by alarmManager. I want this method to call another method written on the dart side. How can I make this happen?

Comment: most likely you need https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html

Comment: I don't think Event Channel can be used for 2 way communication

Comment: it can, you put events into the channel on kotlin side and listen to those events on dart side, call any function you want in the stream.listen lambda https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platform-using-m/50188557#50188557

Answer (score 1):

[MethodChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html) works in both directions.

Create another channel for methods dart provides. Call [setMethodCallHandler](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/setMethodCallHandler.html) to handle incoming methods in dart and then call [invokeMethod](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.html#invokeMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) from Android invoke one.

Comment: There's no need to create another channel; you can use the normal Dart->native channel bidirectionally.

Comment: How will I use the invokeMethod from a different Activity which is triggered by the alarmManager?

Comment: Check out https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager